# How to create a link button similar to Facebook Edit button using asp.net

Tags: jquery

Once in your life time you might have wondered the design of fb comments, fb likes, fb share... and bla bla..

Ok, So I will come to my point now :)

We have designed a blog page. We are able to fetch live chat details from db.. Now the requirement is I need to add dynamically a link button ("edit" text). 
In FB also we have the "edit comment" link button. any idea how to design this.

I tried a few. But its not meeting the requirement. Always some bugs.

Upon clicking the "edit" button, a input textbox dialogue must open letting us to edit the text.

Comment: simply show the edit button on mouseover, and onclick replace the html on the div with an input containing the text. then handle the enter button and set the html of the div with the text entered in the input..

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
$(..commentDiv..).html("<input class='editText' type=text value='"+oldValue+"'/>");

                    var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
                    press.ctrlKey = false;
                    press.which = 13;
                    $(".editText").trigger(press);
                    $('.editText').focus();

                    $('.editText').each(function(i,input){
                        $(input).unbind("keypress");
                        $(input).keypress(function (e) {
                        if (e.which == 13) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
                           }
                        });
                    })
```